# How do I extract sentences in regex that are separated by a word followed by a semicolon?

Tags: javascript, regex

I'm trying to write some regex pattern to take out the location, features, and payment accepted sections from a block of text. I'm making a website that shows food options and in the API, they have a description section that includes more than enough information which is why I want to extract specific text.

I looked into positive and negative lookahead in regex but I still wasn't able to solve my problem. I'm able to select everything up to the second section but only if in this case I was selecting the location. If i was selecting the features, I would be also selecting the previous section, location. See the below text as an example.

Here's the text from which I want to extract from:

> Location: Village 1 \r\n\r\nFeatures:  A multitude of
>   offerings, including entrees, hot meals, wood-fired pizza, salad bar,
>   grill items, made-to-order deli sandwiches & wraps, convenience
>   items and much more\r\n\r\nPayment accepted: cash, Watcard
>    \r\n\r\nThis is a great place to meet your friends! The aroma of
>   fresh baked breads and pastries from our in-house UW Bakery will
>   surely make you take a deep breath. Mudie’s offers a large
>   selection of vegetarian foods, grab n’ go items, salad bar,
>   grill items, made-to-order deli sandwiches and pitas, full breakfast,
>   and convenience foods. A hot entrée item and side dishes are available
>   every lunch and dinner hour.\r\n\r\nMeal hours for Mom's
>   Counter*:\r\n\r\nBreakfast: 7:30 - 11:00 am\r\n\r\nLunch:11:30 am
>   - 2:00 pm\r\n\r\nDinner: 4:30 - 8:00 pm \r\n\r\n*please note, these hours are subject to change without notice "

I wrote this so far:

```
  /.+?(?=Payment accepted)/
```

which selects everything up to Payment Accepted section. I also wrote

```
/(Location|Features|Payment accepted):\s{1,4}?[A-Z]+\s?\d?/
```

where it selects the section of my three desired places. I'm not able to connect the two or to come up with anything that is able to select what I need without including another section.
Any help would be appreciated.

So in the above case, my extracted parts would be:

```
Location: Village 1
Features: &nbsp;A multitude of offerings, including entrees, hot meals, wood-fired pizza, salad bar, grill items, made-to-order deli sandwiches &amp; wraps, convenience items and much more
Payment accepted: cash, Watcard
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use this regex for extracting those three sections of text,

```
/Location:\s*([^\v]*)\s*Features:\s*([^\v]*)Payment accepted:(.*?)(?=\r\n)/
```

Here is the JS code for same.

```js
    var myString = "Location: Village 1 \r\n\r\nFeatures:  A multitude of offerings, including entrees, hot meals, wood-fired pizza, salad bar, grill items, made-to-order deli sandwiches & wraps, convenience items and much more\r\n\r\nPayment accepted: cash, Watcard  \r\n\r\nThis is a great place to meet your friends! The aroma of fresh baked breads and pastries from our in-house UW Bakery will surely make you take a deep breath. Mudie’s offers a large selection of vegetarian foods, grab n’ go items, salad bar, grill items, made-to-order deli sandwiches and pitas, full breakfast, and convenience foods. A hot entrée item and side dishes are available every lunch and dinner hour.\r\n\r\nMeal hours for Mom's Counter*:\r\n\r\nBreakfast: 7:30 - 11:00 am\r\n\r\nLunch:11:30 am - 2:00 pm\r\n\r\nDinner: 4:30 - 8:00 pm \r\n\r\n*please note, these hours are subject to change without notice "; // I want "abc"

    var arr = /Location:\s*([^\v]*)\s*Features:\s*([^\v]*)Payment accepted:([^\r\n]*)/.exec(myString);

    console.log("Location --> "+arr[1]);
    console.log("Features --> "+arr[2]);
    console.log("Payment accepted --> "+arr[3]);
```

Answer (score 0):

If I'm understanding this correctly and you're sure that the sections come in the same repeating order, then you can just put those regex back to back for each section.

[Is something like this what you were looking for?](https://regexr.com/45dd7)

`Location:\s?([\w\d ]+)\s{1,5}Features:\s+(.+)\s{1,5}Payment accepted:\s?(.+)`

Comment: Could you include the regex itself in the answer instead of a link only?